# C# LINQ Find List Inside Another List, Better way to code this than a foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists. npcData and eventData. There must be a better way to do this than in a foreach loop.

```
    foreach (Npc npc in npcData)
    {
        if (npc.active)
        {
            tempNpc.Add(npc);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Event plan in eventData.Where(x => x.can_display))
            {
                if (plan.npc_id == npc.id && !tempNpc.Contains(npc))
                {
                    tempNpc.Add(npc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The dotnet fiddle is [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2wvWlV)

This should return the result 
1 Fred
2 Wilma
3 Barney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = npcData.Where(
    n => n.active == true || 
    eventData.Any(e => e.can_display == true && e.npc_id == n.id)
);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Awesome thank you. Tried googling and couldn't find anything relevant to searching like this.